# A name for all AA, NA, SA, ... Organizations/Communities?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, titles, initialisms

There is this organization/fellowship/support community for alcoholics called 
Alcoholics Anonymous. For sex or porn addiction, the organization/fellowship/support community is called *Sexaholics Anonymous*. And so there are similar organizations/fellowships/support communities for other forms of addictions.

What to say when we want to refer to this kind of organizations/fellowships/communities, and not to any particular one of them. Is there a name to be used for all of them. If not, what would you suggest to be used when we want to refer to all those but not just one of them.

Comment: Simply _support groups_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But that includes other kinds of support groups too.

Comment: "Addiction support groups"? btw I know you don't mean "port addicts" but it certainly brought a smile to my face - I could even name a few.

Comment: I've seen them called *Twelve Step programs.*  More generally they would be *addiction support groups* as Jeremy suggested.

Comment: @aparente001 Both JeremyC's suggestion and yours are good ones. So maybe you like to offer them as answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen them called **Twelve Step programs** (based on the original Alcoholics Anonymous format). More generally they would be *addiction support groups* as Jeremy suggested.